# Is there anything wrong with throw new Exception("Operation Completed Successfully"); for returning validation result?

Tags: php, exception

Is it common to use Exceptions to pass result states of operations or should I only use the function returns for passing values?

The operation results would be kept close to each other when I use exceptions, otherwise, using exceptions for errors and usin a return value for successful operations is another choice.

I was also thinking of extending the exception class and add more data to the validation result instead of returning an array from a validation function.

I am unsure and I'd like to hear your expericences and which method is more common.

edit:
currently I am thinking of doing something like this instead of using exceptions. (for archiving the experience.)

```
switch(login())
case: "success": /* success code; */ break;
case: "wrongpassword": $messagestoshow[]="wrong password"; break; 
...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it common to use Exceptions to pass result states of operations or should I only use the function returns for passing values?

I don't think its common. I **hope** its not common.

> The operation results would be kept close to each other when I use exceptions, otherwise, using exceptions for errors and usin a return value for successful operations is another choice.

There are two logical flows within your function, one is the expected one that ends returning a value on a successful operation, the other one has many exit points (one for each possible source of an exception). Using an exception to return a value, instead of using the function's return value, its simply an abuse.

The discussion for when is a situation exceptional is somewhat loose. Some language use exceptions to flag situations like end-of-iteration *(Python)*, while in others throwing an exception could cause unwanted effects that should only arise in exceptional situations *(C++)*.

Answer (score 4):

It is a common design mantra to say that exceptions should not be used as GOTOs (essentially what you are doing in this case).  Instead, you should rely on the return value.

Exceptions should always be treated as just that: exceptions.  If something unexpected happens that the code is not prepared to handle (an exception), you should throw (and hopefully catch) the exception to handle it appropriately.

Using an exception for success breaks the control flow of your code.  Even using an exception for non-exceptional errors (e.g. an expected validation failure) is abusive.

Where I work, we log all exceptions our website throws and I look these over every day.  I'd be really annoyed if properly working code was adding a ton of exceptions to this list.

Answer (score 2):

It's clearly an abuse of exceptions to signal that something succeeded, and I'd definitely not recommend it.

Exceptions should be used for *exceptional* circumstances, and success is not exceptional. Use a return value instead.

Answer (score 1):

Exceptions are for **exceptional** events.  It is highly inefficient to use them to simply return values from functions.